# Advice on creating a SAM template for an application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli

I am relatively new to infrastructure-as-code, and understand the basic ideas. I have recently been tasked with creating a SAM template for a rather large serverless application, and I just want to see if anyone has a little guidance or perhaps a suggestion on how I can achieve this. I am not sure if what I need to do is even possible within the SAM framework to be honest...
The application has a vue.js frontend, that is stored on s3, which calls API gateway, which calls lambda, which is connected to 3 dynamodb tables. Auth is all handled by Cognito.

Can I define and link these various microservices/components within SAM or cloudformation easily? Are there alternative solutions? Any resources to recommend (Obviously the documentation, but sometimes an example can be immensely useful)

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: There's a good cognito example on the SAM github repo: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/tree/master/examples/2016-10-31/api_cognito_auth

Comment: It looks like there's also a DDB + Lambda + APIGW example: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/tree/master/examples/2016-10-31/api_backend

I don't know about storing it in S3, I haven't done something like that yet.